# Different ways to define Kripke structure

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, philosophy, kripke-models

The Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_structure_(model_checking)#Example has an example of a Kripke structure $M = (S,R,L)$; however, others define Kripke structures as $M = (S,R,V)$ where $V$ is called the valuation.

What is the difference between these two definitions?

They seem to be symmetric, so it might not make a difference, but I want to understand the difference.

Comment: The *labeling* $L$ acts exactly a *valuation* function: it assigns to every state in $S$ the set of atomic prop $p_i$ (i.e. a subset of $AP$) that a true in it.